# What are pros and cons of health sharing memberships when compared with the employer sponsored health plan?

Tags: health

### This question is from the US.

I am thinking of ditching the employer sponsored heath plan for the next year as my out of pocket premium is astronomical.

What are pros and cons of **health sharing memberships** when compared with the employer sponsored health plan? What to look for when choosing a health sharing memberships plan?

Per my research health sharing is a cost-saving alternative to conventional insurance but it is not insurance.

What are some of the pros and cons of health sharing memberships?

1. Premiums are paid post-tax
2. Benefit payments are taxable
3. Total saving for healthy people can be significant
4. More freedom, less regulation
5. No network restriction
6. Potentially steeply discounted pricing as cash payers
7. Members don’t get Affordable Care Act subsidies

What to look for when choosing one?

1. Are per-existing conditions excluded?
2. Do people with per-existing conditions qualify?
3. Is there a waiting period?
4. Is there a cap, yearly or a total cap the membership will pay
5. What expenses are excluded?

Comment: Are you talking about a (real) HMO, or something else? I have no idea what a "health sharing membership" is... and suspect it's too poorly defined to discuss in the abstract.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere do you have a suggestion where this question should be moved to?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Is there a page or information defining workplace so that we all can review before ganging up on this question and causing it to close? 

I though questions about health benefits provided by employers are related to workplace, it is where there benefits are decided, debated, where enrollments happen.

Oh, I just noticed that you removed your comments asking everyone to gang up to close this question. I thank you for that! Unfortunately this post was as a result downvoted, damage already done. It looks like people overreacted and had no appreciation for my effort.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Which section here workplace.stackexchange.com/help is applicable and support your request for flagging this question? You are incorrect, some employers are now reaching out outside the traditional model. Even if your employer does not give you such option, it is still an option, something employees can discuss at their workplace. The costs of the traditional insurance is getting to the point where it is out of reach for many so some of us are looking into alternatives and want to know cons and pros vs the traditional mode.

Answer (score 2):

We have been using a health share for about 3 years and we are extremely happy with it.

**Disclaimers:**

1. No endorsement or advertisement intended, this is just
   one data point of a personal experience.
2. My answers are informed by our Health Share
   (https://zionhealthshare.org/) and I don't know to what extent it
   can be generalized.

**Pros:**

1. Very cheap as compared to Affordable Care Act plans
2. Deductibles are "per event" and not "per year". If you break your leg in December, you only pay once.
3. Astonishingly good customer service. When you call, someone picks up the phone immediately, they know what they are talking about and are extremely helpful. For example when we scheduled a covered procedure they issued a "virtual credit card" so we don't have to front the money.
4. Good coverage for preventive care.
5. Very good support for finding providers and negotiating prices.
6. Since I'm self employed the premiums are tax deductible
7. Qualifies in Massachusetts as "good enough" coverage so you don't have to pay the local penalty (which is steep).
8. You do NOT have to deal with regular health insurance, which is a royal pain in the neck.
9. Coverage is worldwide. No network, no need for medical travel insurance, you are covered wherever you are and for whatever services you need.

**Cons:**

1. You are forgoing any benefits from your employer that can be substantial
2. You may have to pay for services up front and should budget for a bit of a cash cushion. This being said, our provider has been very helpful in managing this.
3. Most health care providers are confused by "self payers" these days. It can take a few conversations to get the real "self payer" price, which is typically half of the sticker price.
4. Just another variation of #3: while you technically have access to every provider of your choice, it helps to choose providers that actually know how deal with self payers. One provider called us 6+ times to add our insurance info to an appointment. Some providers don't seem to have a concept of "no insurance". The simple of question "how much does XXX cost" can create the occasional brain freeze.
5. It's good practice to double and triple check bills.
6. Pre-existing conditions have their own rules. Typically it's a "fade in", i.e. there is a cap on benefits that increases over time.
7. Some health shares exclude or limit coverage for bad "life style choices": drugs, smoking, alcohol, etc. There is an expectation that you take some responsibilities for your own health.

**Things to be aware of**

6. Not all health shares are equal. We did a fair bit of research on different providers before signing on. Prices, terms and levels of service vary quite a bit.
7. Pricing is dependent on age. Make you sure you factor this into your budget and decision process.
8. You are doing something "unusual", so many interactions do take a bit more time and a bit more explaining.
9. You can run the numbers in any way you want, but the results will depend a lot on the assumptions which typically involve stuff you can't possibly know. Are you planning to get cancer or break a leg next year or not ?
10. Everyone's situation and assumptions are different. What might be great for me may not be great for you.

**Summary**
We went through this decision process a few years ago and decided to sign up. I couldn't be happier with results.

**<\soap box rant>** Sorry for rant. The health insurance system in the US is fundamentally broken. It has terrible incentives that result in bad outcomes for patients in terms of physical & mental health and money. When I researched affordable care act plans, I was disgusted: the whole bronze, silver, gold, gold plus, platinum, etc. spiel is basically fraudulent. You pay $3600/year in extra premium to save $2500/year in deductible. It makes no sense other than to enrich the insurance. **</soap box rant>**

One of the most unexpected benefits for us was the quality of the interactions.   Talking with conventional health insurance for us has almost always been difficult and controversial. Our health share so far has been the exact opposite: every single interaction has been friendly, collaborative, helpful, and productive.